# Perform function if body id is a specific value

Tags: javascript, function, exists

I'd like to perform a function on only one page of my site where the body has an ID of #modulePage16460412. I have the script below that is not working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if($('#modulePage16460412').length > 0 ) {
$(function()
{
$(window).bind('load',
    function(e)
    {
    window.setTimeout(function()
        {
         $.colorbox({opacity:0.3, href:"/storage/support/colorbox/offer.html"});
        }, /*timeout->*/ 2000);
    });
});
}
</script>
```

Would it also be possible to only execute the function the first time they visit the page and not execute again if they come back to that page?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not have this function in a script and only add it to the HTML on the pages that should use it?

Comment: The second part of your question would need to use cookies or localStorage. I prefer localStorage in this case because the server really does not care about this information so why should it be stored in the cookies and sent to the server.. localStorage exists only on the client.

Comment: Perfect solution scott.korin! Definitely a "why didn't I think of that" moment :) Thanks!

Comment: @rlemon - Do you know of any good resources on how would I do it with localStorage? Thanks!

Comment: I would look on the MDN page for it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage [and here is a quick example](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/ET9Zg/)

Comment: Checked out the link and example. Thanks! localStorage is a mile above this newbies head :) Thanks for the help @rlemon!

Answer (score 1):

You can just put the function on the body load selecting it with the ID specified... if no element exists with this ID then the function will never fire.

```
$('#modulePage16460412').load(function() { // this will not be called unless an element with that ID has loaded into the DOM

     // ... your code here.

});
```

and to touch on the 'single execution' part (this really should be a new question... but ohh well) you can use localStorage to persist the setting.

http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/ET9Zg/

in your case something like

```
if( !getData('someKey') ) {
   // ok so they have not been here.
   setData('someKey', 1); //  now set the data so this won't get hit again.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the condition inside `$(function(){` so that the body tag is actually loaded before the JavaScript queries the (unloaded) DOM for the existence of the ID.

```
$(function(){
    if($('#modulePage16460412').length) {

        ...

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

your defining a function, but not calling anywhere.

so put everything inside some function and call.

and also replace this if($('#modulePage16460412').length > 0 ) with if($('#modulePage16460412')), because when jquery couldnt find element with id : #modulePage16460412, it will return empty array. empty_array.length = 0, so it will always be true.

```
$('document').ready(function(){

if($('#modulePage16460412')) {
$(function()
{
$(window).bind('load',
    function(e)
    {
    window.setTimeout(function()
        {
         $.colorbox({opacity:0.3, href:"/storage/support/colorbox/offer.html"});
        }, /*timeout->*/ 2000);
    });
});
}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a simpler approach?

```
$( document ).ready( function() { // runs code only after DOM ready
   if ( $( '#modulePage16460412' ).length > 0 ) { // runs code only if id found
       window.setTimeout( function() {
          $.colorbox( { opacity:0.3, href:"/storage/support/colorbox/offer.html" } );
       }, 2000 );
   }
} );
```